FM0 (bi-phase space) decoder
I'm looking for the solution for decoding FM0 (bi-phase space) encoded signal from RFID tag. Response from the tag starts with preamble and then followed by 16 bit random number. Link rate is 40kHz. Due to hardware limitation, the signal is high pass filtered with first order RC filter, which has cutoff approximately 26kHz. Currently cutoff is probably too high. My sample rate is 2MSPS.
FM0 symbols are like following:

And preamble is like this:

My typical IQ signal looks like this (SNR can be much lower):

Data can be also found from here:
https://pastebin.com/vDLxjytC
Half bits of the data are:
binary_vector=[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1];

I'm looking for Octave or/and Gnuradio solution for successful decoding of data (with lower SNR). My initial processing flow was:

remove DC offset


I will take average of some samples at beginning of reception and subtract that from IQ data


Utilize matched filter


I have used filter with 25 constant taps (half of the bit). I'm not sure if this optimal solution, since my IQ data is not actually square wave because of HPF? I was trying to recover original IQ data before matched filter by inverting original HPF, but it would cause some low frequency fluctuation.


Timing detector / clock recovery


I would need to have detector for ones and zeros. There is some variation in bit lengths so I would need solution, which can cope that problem. I have read that for example PLL based on the Gardner's timing detector could be used, but I have not figured out, how to implement that? I was looking for Symbol Sync block in Gnuradio, but I could not get it work.

In practice the length of the data can be much longer (hundreds of bits), so timing sync is critical. I have also thinking to adjust phase of my IQ data so I would not need to handle I and Q separately, but I'm not sure how this can be done automatically? Could I use Costas loop?
EDIT:
Here is the code for more challenging scenario (SNR 15dB and real data rate is 41.6kHz, data length 268 half bits).
 close all;
clear;

% Define parameters
Fs = 2e6;   % Sampling frequency (Hz)
data_rate = 40e3; % Data rate (bits per second)


%I parameters
Ai=-0.1526; 
Bi=0.33; 
%Q parameters
Aq=-0.125; 
Bq=-0.36; 
cutoff_frequency = 26000; % Cutoff frequency (Hz)

CW=350; %samples before data
totalS=7500; % number of samples

SNR=15;

preamble='110100100011';

% Define the hex string
hex_string = '3000E28068900000000086C9BD55567A';

% Define a function to convert hex to binary
hex_to_bin = @(hex_char) dec2bin(hex2dec(hex_char), 4);

% Convert each hex character to binary and concatenate
binary_string = arrayfun(hex_to_bin, hex_string, 'UniformOutput', false);
binary_string = strcat(binary_string{:});

% Perform FM0 encoding
encoded_bits = preamble;
prev_bit = encoded_bits(end); % Initialize previous bit
for k = 1:length(binary_string)
    if binary_string(k) == '0'
        
        if prev_bit == '0'
            encoded_bits = [encoded_bits, '1', '0'];
        else
            encoded_bits = [encoded_bits, '0', '1'];
        end
    else
        
        if prev_bit == '0'
            encoded_bits = [encoded_bits, '1', '1'];
        else
            encoded_bits = [encoded_bits, '0', '0'];
        end
    end
    % Update the previous bit
    prev_bit = encoded_bits(end);
end

% Display the encoded bits
disp(['Encoded bits: ', encoded_bits]);

binary_vector=[];
temp=0;
for k=1:length(encoded_bits)
    binary_vector(k)=str2num(encoded_bits(k));

end


% Define the duration of each bit (in samples)
bit_duration = 24; % ideal 25 there can be error +/- 1 

% Initialize the vector for the signal
signal = [];

% Iterate through the binary vector
for bit = binary_vector
    % Generate samples for each bit
    if bit == 1
        bit_samples = ones(1, bit_duration);
    else
        bit_samples = zeros(1, bit_duration);
    end

    % Append the samples to the signal vector
    signal = [signal, bit_samples];
end




desired=zeros(1,CW);
desired=[desired signal];
desired=[desired zeros(1,totalS-length(desired))];

%ideal clock

duration = totalS/Fs; % Duration of the signal in seconds

% Time vector
t = (0:1/Fs:duration-1/Fs);

% Generate square wave
square_wave = 0.1*square(2*pi*data_rate*t);



figure;
plot(desired);
hold on;
plot(square_wave);
hold off;
title('Desired output');
axis([0 totalS -2 2]);
grid on;


% Design a first-order high-pass Butterworth filter
[filter_b, filter_a] = butter(1, cutoff_frequency / (Fs / 2), 'high');

HPF_desired = filter(filter_b, filter_a, desired);


I_data=Ai+Bi*HPF_desired;
Q_data=Aq+Bq*HPF_desired;

figure;
plot(I_data);
hold on;
plot(Q_data);
plot(square_wave);
hold off;
grid on;

IQ_with_noise=awgn(I_data+i*Q_data,SNR);

figure;
plot(real(IQ_with_noise));
hold on;
plot(imag(IQ_with_noise));
plot(square_wave    );
hold off;
grid on;

Plots are following:




Hmm... don't you get the original square wave restored directly from your IQ data file (by looping the file, no need for filtering)? In IQ data, phase turns can be located by looking locations where data gets positive values.

This example case would be easy as SNR is good and length of the data is small. I need to be able to handle situation where SNR is low and clock is not exactly 40kHz.

Please find the edited post.

Is time vector OK in your source code?

Should be. Why you think it is not?

Damn, looked too fast the source ... .

Updated my answer and source code. Added square wave recovery plot for the IQ data saved from your edit source code and updated the code to handle 24-bit duration).

I tried another approach to get the square wave restored from linked IQ data. After looking the data I noticed that turning points of square wave are those positive values (first ones after changing from negative to positive) on both I and Q data so that when I(n) is positive it marks to turn the bit(n) ON and when Q(n) is positive it marks turn the bit(n) OFF. So, by finding out these turning points, which comes alternating, one gets the square wave constructed by filling the bits between the turns.
Here's my Octave source code for the job (which has not tested with any other data but what OP has posted so, modifications maybe needed...):
pkg load signal
pkg load control

close all;
clear;
clf;

format long;

Fs = 2e6;             % Sampling frequency (Hz)

%data=load("ysiaDBsb.txt");  % from older post
data=load("IQdata12019267.txt"); 

I_values=data(:,1); 
Q_values=data(:,2);

bit_duration = 24;

vcount = length(I_values);

%find square wave starting point (preampble tag [1 0 1 0 v 1] here)
n = 0;
do 
  n++;
until !signbit(I_values(n)) % 1st phase turn found
% read v value if needed


t = 0:1/Fs:(vcount-1)/Fs;
k = l = m = n;

% find phase turns from I data
V = zeros(2, vcount);

for n = n:bit_duration:vcount
  if (!signbit(I_values(n))) % is phase turned
    V(:, n) = [1, n];
  endif
endfor

% find phase turns from Q data
for m = m:bit_duration:vcount
  if (!signbit(Q_values(m))) % is phase turned
    V(:, m) = [0, m];
  endif
endfor

% fill bits between phase turns
bit = 0;
last_turn = 0;
recovered_squarewave = zeros(1, vcount);
do
  if (V(2, l) > 0)
    bit = V(1, l);
    last_turn = l;  % info used in plotting the "window" markers (upper plot)
  endif
  
  V(1, l) = bit;
  recovered_squarewave(l) = V(1, l);
  l++;
until (l == vcount)
V
% adjust gain if needed --------------------------------------------
GdB = -3; % dB
gain = 10^(GdB/20);
gain_a = 1;
gain_b = gain;

recovered_squarewave = filter(gain_b, gain_a, recovered_squarewave);
% -------------------------------------------------------------------

% matched filter
matched_filter=ones(1,bit_duration); 
matched_filter=filter(matched_filter,bit_duration,recovered_squarewave);

figure(1);
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(recovered_squarewave, 'linewidth', 1, '-k');
hold on;
plot(matched_filter, 'linewidth', 1, '--r');
hold on;
for k = k:bit_duration*2:last_turn
    if (mod(k, bit_duration) = 0)
      plot([k,k],[1*gain,1.05*gain], '--k');
    else
      plot([k,k],[1*gain,1.2*gain], '--k');
    endif
    hold on;
endfor
hold off;
title('Recovered Square Wave and its Matched Filter (sample)');
legend("recovered squarewave", "matched filter");
axis([0 vcount -0.1 1.1]);
grid on;
xlabel('Sample');ylabel('A');

subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(t,recovered_squarewave, 'linewidth', 1, '-k');
hold on;
plot(t,matched_filter, 'linewidth', 1, '--r');
hold off;
title('Recovered Square Wave and its Matched Filter (time)');
legend("recovered squarewave", "matched filter");
axis([0 vcount/Fs -0.1 1.1]);
grid on;

xlabel('Time(s)');ylabel('A');

audiowrite('recovered_squarewave.wav',recovered_squarewave, Fs);
audiowrite('matched_filtered_square_wave.wav',matched_filter, Fs);

which results as:

EDIT:
Here's square wave recovery plot for the IQ data saved from your edit source code (had to update the code to handle 24-bit duration):

Noisy IQ data with SNR=30.
EDIT: Ran test, where SNR=25 and noisy IQ data generated using OP's source code, resulted bit-accurate recovery of the square wave.
So, SNR value around 25 seemed to be the worst case for noise it could handle perfectly (with this data) but, it's maybe not final value since test was done w/o real life signal data (and my reader implementation is not whole).

Your code works once SNR is high and data rate is perfect. I think position of preamble can be found with correlator and then I think you need to adapt your clock with some kind of PLL approach.

Challenge is that I don't know if bit duration exactly in advance. It can be 24 or 26 or 24.34. I need solution, which adapts to data rate. Data rate can change 2% during the response.
